# Android app crashing with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid payload item type error

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app which is using the DrawerLayout and ActionbarCompat library. i have some customers reporting a crash in the Android Developer console.

Here is the Stacktrace for the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid payload item type
at android.util.EventLog.writeEvent(Native Method)
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2765)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:372)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivity.java:232)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:159)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivity.java:130)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:295)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$3.onClick(ActionBarView.java:172)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4120)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17112)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4905)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

has anyone come across this issue? is there anything i am doing wrong for this to occur.

The reported devices are mostly LG Optimus series of devices and this happens when user presses the Top Left Menu to open the Drawer.

Let me add that the app is not setting the title or formatted text in the menu. i suppress the title text using displayOptions in theme style definition

```
<style name="theme_light_ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome</item>
</style>
```

The only place i am having title reference is in the Activity's onCreate

```
ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
if (ab != null) {
    ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: I did review that issue reported but it is different from my issue as i am extending my activity from ActionBarActivity and i am not setting the actionbar title or any formatting for Menu Items.

Comment: Please post your menu XML and the `title` references.

Comment: The crash is occuring when you press the Hamburger icon to open the DrawerLayout. When i press the menu button, the menu is loading fine.